# Onchange Function for a range input

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.JS for  building a range input slider.The value of `min` , `max` and `value` have been set by `{this.renderMinTotal()}` and `{this.renderMaxTotal()}`.The main problem is that when I try to toggle it it does not move at all.I know that I should use `onChange handler` but I do not know what to write.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      library: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/json.bc", {
      method: "get"
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'));
        this.setState(
          state => ({
            ...state,
            data: Maindata
          }),
          () => {
            this.reorganiseLibrary();
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({
      library,

    });
  };
  handlePerPage = evt =>
    this.setState(
      {
        perPage: evt.target.value
      },
      () => this.reorganiseLibrary()
    );

  renderMinTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMin = Math.min(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return acc === undefined ? libMin : libMin < acc ? libMin : acc;
    }, undefined);
  };

  renderMaxTotal = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    return library.reduce((acc, lib) => {
      const libMax = Math.max(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom));
      return libMax > acc ? libMax : acc;
    }, 0);
  };

 handlerChange = evt =>{
    let value = evt.target.value
 ///what should be written here///////
 }

  render() {
    const { library } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            min={this.renderMinTotal()}
            max={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            value={this.renderMaxTotal()}
            step="1000"
            className="multirange"
           onChange={this.handlerChange}
          />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: it would be easier for others to help if you can describe what you want to achieve with range input. What is your value state?

Comment: I have a `json` file containing an array and in the array there are plenty of `totalCom` fields.I found the `max` and `min` value of all `totalCom` by `{this.renderMinTotal()}` and `{this.renderMaxTotal()}` and I want the value of `min` and `max` and `value `of `input` be the output of `{this.renderMinTotal()}` and `{this.renderMaxTotal()}`.

Answer (score 1):

i don't see reason to load value of your range-input from

```
( this.renderMaxTotal() )
```

try just leaving value blank, later on try f.e.

```
onChange={(event)=>{console.log(event.target.value)}}
```

Comment: The value of input is going to be the output  of `{this.renderMaxTotal()}`.